# Convert Outlook contacts copy&paste style txt to C# object

Tags: c#, regex

Outlook contacts copy&paste style txt :
[image]

```
Full Name: Ryan ryan_liang
ryan_liang, Ryan
ryan_liang@demo.com

Full Name: Shawn shawn
shawn, Shawn
shawn@demo.com
```

Expected Result :

```
[
    {
        FullName:"Ryan ryan_liang",
        Mail:"ryan_liang@demo.com"
    },
    {
        FullName:"Shawn shawn",
        Mail:"shawn@demo.com"
    }
]
```

What I've tried :
I can get the fullname by below code, but if full name like  `Ryan ryan_liang` then system only get `Ryan`.
And I have no idea to get mail by regex.

```
void Main()
{
    var txt = @"
Full Name: Ryan ryan_liang
ryan_liang, Ryan
ryan_liang@demo.com

Full Name: Shawn shawn
shawn, Shawn
shawn@demo.com  
    ";
    
    var result = Regex.Matches(txt, @"Full Name: (?<Name>\w+)").Cast<Match>()
        .Select(s => new {FullName=s.Groups["Name"].Value});
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I recommend using a [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=net-5.0) to read it by line.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to retrieve contacts for Outlook, either the local application or the cloud-based version, you can use the proper API. If Outlook connects to Exchange Server the contacts are stored on the server anyway

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I just want to convert this style txt to c# objects, and I have no right to use API, they just give me the txt file

Comment: The "expected result" is a JSON string - an array containing objects with `FullName` and `Mail` properties. If you create an array of C# objects with those properties, any JSON library will serialize them in the form you posted.

Comment: @Wei there's no such style so what you try to do is anything but "just". Again, if you want to retrieve the contacts from a local application, just use the API. Your code is running with the end user's credentials so you can definitely talk to the app

Comment: @Wei `they just give me the txt file` who's "they"? BTW removing the screenshot just made this question incomprehensible. Because there's simply no `Outlook contacts copy&paste style`. Windows Clipboard doesn't have "styles". When you copy from an application, the application puts data in the clipboard in *multiple* formats, ranging from simple text, to formatted text, HTML and composite objects. When you paste, Windows sends to the target application the best format it understands.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, the supervisor of my company, their computer can't run any third-party exe, because the AD control.

Comment: @Wei it runs Outlook already. Even if this is a web interface,  instead of copying "they" could export the contacts directly anyway. It doesn't matter though - to generate a JSON string you need a JSON serializer.

Comment: Yes, outlook is ok, because the AD IT allow it, if I need to run third-party exe, I need to wait a week for permission, it's a once task...

Comment: @Wei SO is a site about programming questions. This sounds more like an internal miscommunication issue. In any case, parsing the format you posted doesn't need regular expressions. You can read 3 lines at a time and skip the fourth to get each record. You can get the full name from each line simply by skipping `Full Name; ` and retrieve the email from the third

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's a good way, I'm trying  your way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple parser :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var txt = @"
Full Name: Ryan ryan_liang
ryan_liang, Ryan
ryan_liang@demo.com

Full Name: Shawn shawn
shawn, Shawn
shawn@demo.com  
    ";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(txt);
            string line = "";
            int rowCount = 0;
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            Person person = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Full Name"))
                    {
                        string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        person = new Person() { title = splitArray[1].Trim() };
                        people.Add(person);
                        rowCount = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (++rowCount)
                        {
                            case 2 :
                                person.name = line;
                                break;
 
                            case 3 :
                                person.email = line;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. Assuming that you are trying to extract information like first name, surename or email from copy&paste contact list, I would rather suggest using positions.

What I mean: from your contacts (or preferably from documentation) you can surely decide at which position in copyed data is relevant information. And you extract it from there based on position (e.g. "first line as a whole" or "second line after colon"). Thus you avoid regexes altogether which is good thing, since they tend to be problematic. With regexes, you need to test them rigorously, there are lot of edge cases and if input can be in several languages and alphabets (e.g. russian or japanesse), you are in for rough ride.